# cannot send emails with Oracle 11g APEX5

Tags: oracle, email, oracle11g, oracle-apex-5

Trying to resolve an issue with sending emails using Oracle APEX5 11g. I've set up the administration settings as per Oracle instructions:

---

SMTP Host Address - Defines the server address of the SMTP server. By default on installation, this is set to localhost. If you are using another server as an SMTP relay, change this parameter to that server's address.

SMTP Host Port - Defines the port the SMTP server listens to for mail requests. The default setting is 25.

SMTP Authentication Username - If you enter a username, Oracle Application Express authenticates against it when sending emails. Prior to Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.2), only the SMTP authentication scheme "LOGIN" is supported. On newer database versions, all authentication schemes of UTL_SMTP are supported.

SMTP Authentication Password - If you enter a password, Oracle Application Express authenticates against it when sending emails. Prior to Oracle Database 11g Release 2, Release 11.2.0.2, only the SMTP authentication scheme "LOGIN" is supported. On newer database versions, all authentication schemes of UTL_SMTP are supported.

Use SSL/TLS - Beginning with Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.2), Oracle Application Express supports secure SMTP connections. Options include:

Yes - A secure connection with SSL/TLS is made before SMTP communication.

After connection is established - Oracle Application Express sends the SMTP command STARTTLS immediately after the connection is opened.

No - A non-secure connection is opened.

Default Email From Address - Defines the from address for tasks that generate email, such as approving a provision request or resetting a password.

---

I have also run the 'Granting Connect Privileges' script in sqlplus as sysdba as per Oracle instruction for pre 12c:

---

```
DECLARE
  ACL_PATH  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  -- Look for the ACL currently assigned to '*' and give APEX_050000
  -- the "connect" privilege if APEX_050000 does not have the privilege yet.

  SELECT ACL INTO ACL_PATH FROM DBA_NETWORK_ACLS
   WHERE HOST = '*' AND LOWER_PORT IS NULL AND UPPER_PORT IS NULL;

  IF DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CHECK_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH, 'APEX_050000',
     'connect') IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(ACL_PATH,
     'APEX_050000', TRUE, 'connect');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  -- When no ACL has been assigned to '*'.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL('power_users.xml',
    'ACL that lets power users to connect to everywhere',
    'APEX_050000', TRUE, 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL('power_users.xml','*');
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

---

Is there more that I need to configure within the application in terms of adding any package, procedure etc..??

Whenever I try to use the APEX send EMail procedure or run standard APEX_MAIL.SEND PL/SQL Code I just cannot get my application to send an email from my SMTP server (either Gmail or BT Internet) I have never tried to set up email from my own PC using a localhost environment as I am doing now, only done it before from a work environment which is all configured. Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured the ACL? Access Control Lists are necessary to be configured so you can send mail or access the internet. There is information in this blog post:http://www.dadbm.com/enable-oracle-database-to-send-emails-via-smtp-server/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create the ACL and assign it to your user APEX_050000.

Second point, you need to ensure that the connection is using SSL Certificate, and if it is, you have to create a wallet and install the appropiate certificate (.crt) to send emails from external smtp. Here you will find the details:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-application-express-apex-ldap-authentication

Answer (score 0):

```
declare

    v_user_name varchar2(100);
    v_password varchar2(100);

begin

    select USERNAME,PASSWORD into v_user_name,v_password from tbl_us where upper(email) = upper(EMAIL); APEX_MAIL.SEND(
    p_to                        =>lower(your_email),
    p_from                      =>'admin@abc.com',
    p_body                      =>null,
    p_subj                      =>'Password for Customer Login',
    p_cc                        => NULL,
    p_bcc                       =>NULL,
    p_replyto                   =>null);

    APEX_MAIL.PUSH_QUEUE;
end;
```